# How do I show the size of an Image file in media2 after selecting the image?

Tags: media

After selecting an Image field using the media browser, in the edit form the selected shows image, an edit button, a delete button, and an "include file in display" checkbox.

How Do I add the size of the image in the same display?[image]

Q2: 
In a colourbox popup display, which seems to only pick the "title" , I cant get this to read html. Is there a way of enable html as I need some text in Italics, and in Bold? [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. This is Q&A site, not a forum, questions should be separate entities.

Comment: Have made the adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Somehow undocumented is the fact that this uses the "Preview" view mode. Editing that and ensuring its the one selected in image view changed everything to working normally.

Thanks.